# Fetching whole source code of a website android

Tags: android

I wrote an application which fetches data from a website. But I can't see image links etc. in this app. I need to access the complete source code of a website. On the other words, I need the source code which is shown when you choose view page source option in chrome. Here is my code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    readWebpage(textView);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
    }
}


public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://web.mit.edu/" });

    }
}`
```

In this link first image is what I get, second one is what I want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWOWr.jpg

Comment: I only see one image on the linked page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
textView.setText(result);
```

You're probably receiving your downloaded information correctly. You're just not presenting it correctly. Don't present it as HTML, just as plain text.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark answer as correct. Thanks!